# Migrating from bootstrap 3.0.0 to 3.0.1

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I actually tried to upgrade from bootstrap 3.0.0 to 3.0.3 and experienced a problem.  So I rolled back versions of bootstrap and determined that the issue first presents in bootstrap 3.0.1.

When I upgrade my columns are all shifted horrifically.  I realize I am asking a question without posting any source, but I would like to know if there is a migration guide for moving from 3.0.0 to later versions of bootstrap or any any things I should be looking out for?

I was surprised by the drastic changes in such a minor version upgrade.  I wonder if I must have been applying bootstrap incorrectly, or did others face similar work in retrofitting their app?

Comment: I know I've come in late on this, but did you ever find a solution? I want to upgrade from 3.0 to make use of the xs-offsets, but the horrible column shifting, even in 3.1, has forced me to stick with 3.0 until I find the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at what was modified in the doc: http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2013/10/29/bootstrap-3-0-1-released , I hate what they are doing ... can't follow with the upgrades without having to do tons of modifications .

Comment: I feared that would be the case (sort through the change logs). I really was hoping there would be a guide.  I don't need to upgrade, perhaps the better path forward us to wait until there is something "Better" that I need to upgrade for, and then redesign ground up?